# SVN: вопросы по merge, Idea.

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

1) Сижу что-то пишу, обновился, конфликты, померджился и устранил конфликты. Вопрос: я передумал, можно ли снести это обновление и повторить его еще раз? Или вообще отказаться.

2) Можно ли посмотреть в IntellijIdea все различия между локальной версией кода и последней ревизией? Я имею ввиду не один файл, а удобно пробежаться по всему проекту.

3) Я веду работу в некоей ветке. Мне надо перенести результаты своей работы в другую ветку. Однако я не хочу переносить ВСЕ различия между ветками т.к. в процессе работы мне приходилось обновляться, и эти обновления во второй ветке не нужны. Другими словами, мне надо перенести из своей ветки в другую некоторый выделенный набор различий между ветками. Как это сделать? Ведь если я сделаю merge, то перенесется все.

4) Очень неудобная вещь: похоже что SVN проверяет строки по номеру. В итоге такая ситуация: я добавил метод в класс, кто-то добавил другой метод и закомитил быстрее меня, я обновляюсь и делаю merge, если я жму в принять свой вариант - чужой код удаляется. Не помогает даже визуальный Merge Tool в Идее: все равно при нажатии на стрелочку он вставляет мой или чужой код на одно и то же конфликтное место, а надо бы чтобы вставил оба кода. Неудобно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скажу честно, что как это сделать в Idea - понятия не имею, так как им не пользуюсь, но как те же задачи решить с помощью [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/), могу подсказать.

1. Если в вашей рабочей копии есть БОЛЬШИЕ изменения, то для сохранности их перед обновлением (Update), равно как и перед слиянием, сделайте патч этих самых изменений. Далее проводите обновление/слияние. Если результат вас не устраивает, то откатываете ВСЕ изменения рабочей копии (Revert), затем применяете сохраненный патч со своими изменениями (apply patch). Ваша рабочая копия в исходном состоянии!
2. Можно посмотреть с помощью TortoiseSVN.
3. SVN позволяет [переносить при слиянии только необходимые вам ревизии](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/ru/svn.branchmerge.copychanges.html), т.е. *конкретные* изменения. Разумеется, если за одну выкладку (Commit) вы выкладываете несвязанные между собой множественные изменения, то переносить их в другие ветки окажется нетривиальной задачей и без ручной работы будет не обойтись.
4. Недобство ли? Не жмите "использовать мой файл", это неправильно. Т.к. описанная ситуация для SVN - явно конфликтная, то вам придется вручную указывать, *как именно* надо объединять изменения. Следует выбрать иной режим слияния для данного фрагмента, например,  "использовать мой блок кода после чужого", тогда и ваши, и чужие изменения сохранятся. Сами представьте - 2 человека добавили какой-то новый код в одну позицию в файле. Как решить, какой код должен идти раньше? А может вообще они написали одно и то же, и 2 варианта не нужно? Разрешить подобные вопросы SVN никак не сможет, да и вряд ли другая система на это окажется способной.

Кстати, для целей слияния можно использовать различные инструменты: TortoiseMerge, WinMegre, и пр. Попробуйте другие средства кроме вашего, может, они вам больше подойдут.

Comment: По поводу пункта 3 - активное использование `cherry-pick` в `Subversion` и, вообще говоря, любой `VCS`, может очень быстро привести к большому количеству проблем и путанице. Намного лучше **всегда** использовать `feature-branch`'и и считать атомарной операцией `merge` ветки, а не `cherry-pick` конкретного `changeset'a`.

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, в целом вы возможно правы, однако на практике не всегда получается полностью синхронизировать ветки. Например, при создании релизной ветки под выпускаемый продукт в нее переносятся только те изменения из ствола, которые реально необходимы для данного релиза.

Comment: @vladimir_ki Да, согласен. Другое дело, что, пожалуй, бэкпорт чейндсетов и веток (и все связанные проблемы) выходят за рамки данного вопроса :)

Comment: Порекомендую Beyond Compare 3. 3-way merge просто шикарен у них.